# Schengen visa - 90/180 rule

Tags: schengen, 90-180-visa-rules

Do I have to leave the country on my 180th day even though I haven't spent 90 days? (Let's say I spent 63 days.)

Once I hit the 180 days, how long do I have to wait to be able to re-enter the Schengen states?

Can I leave for a few days and re-enter?

Or do I have to wait three months to re-enter?

Comment: You have to leave if your 63rd day adds up to 90 days within the previous 180 days.  Marking this as a duplicate.

Comment: There is no 180th day, you have to consider all 180-day periods, it's a sliding window. If you have spent 63 days in the last 180 days in the Schengen area, then you can certainly stay for another 27 days, possibly more depending on how your 63 days are distributed. Because of this, leaving and reentering does not buy you anything, there is no notion of being granted a period of stay or starting a new 180-day period.